# Store the file extensions from a given file list in a list using list comprehension

Tags: python

I'm making a small script that organizes all the files inside a folder creating individual folders for each file type and then moving all the files into the corresponding folders.

I've already made the script and it works but my goal is to make it a bit more compact using list comprehension.

I would like to turn this:

```
import os

dir_path = '.'

files = [f for f in os.listdir(dir_path) if os.path.isfile(f)]
file_types = []

for file in files:
    ext = file.split('.')[1]
    if ext not in file_types:
        file_types.append(ext)
```

Into something like this:

```
import os

dir_path = '.'

files = [f for f in os.listdir(dir_path) if os.path.isfile(f)]
file_types = [f.split('.')[1] for f in files if f not in file_types]
```

But I get the following error:

```
file_types = [f.split('.')[1] for f in files if f not in file_types]
NameError: name 'file_types' is not defined
```

There are probably many different ways of doing this witout using list comprehension but I'd like to find a solution doing it this way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list comprehension will not work because you are trying to reference the list you are creating. You can achieve you desired output using `set`:

```
file_types = list(set([f.split('.')[1] for f in files]))
```

By converting the list to a set, you remove any duplicate items, then you can use `list()` to convert the set back to a list.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need set.
2. You simply extend your (set) comprehension.

`{get_ext(f) f for f in os.listdir(dir_path) if os.path.isfile(f)}`

I can't test it now, but should work fine.

You may `list()` your set later on if you insist on having `list` not `set`. Though, it seems superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

`file_types = [f.split('.')[1] for f in files if f not in file_types]` fails because the right side of a `=` sign is always evaluated before the left side, hence `file_types` does not exist when `[f.split('.')[1] for f in files if f not in file_types]` is evaluated, so it fails.

If you REALLY want it to be a one liner, you can do something like
`file_types = list(set([f.split('.')[1] for f in files]))` but python code (and code in general) should be clear rather than short, in my opinion.
If you are using a set anyway, another option is using a set comprehension `file_types = list({f.split('.')[1] for f in files})`